# Error when switching from ring0 to ring3 in x86

Tags: assembly, operating-system, x86, kernel, bootloader

I am trying to switch from ring0 to ring3 using lret instruction. Therefore, I push correct values for ss, esp, cs, ip, and use lret.

I use qemu and gdb to debug this code, and find a strange thing:

After lret instrunction, the processor successfully switch to ring3 (I use "info registers" in qemu to check that), values for ss, cs, esp are all correct, and eip points to the first instruction of the ring3 code.

However, no matter what the first instruction of the ring3 code is (even nop instruction), qemu will restart (maybe a general protection error?)

Here is the code, header files are from [this repo](https://github.com/guilleiguaran/xv6). The bootloader switches CPU to protected mode and loads the kernel to 0x100000, and the virtual address of the kernel starts at 0x80100000.

```
#include "memlayout.h"
#include "mmu.h"
#include "asm.h"

.text

.globl _start
_start = V2P_WO(entry)

.globl entry
entry:
    mov %cr4, %eax
    or $(CR4_PSE), %eax
    mov %eax, %cr4
    mov $(V2P_WO(pgdir)), %eax
    mov %eax, %cr3
    mov %cr0, %eax
    or $(CR0_PG|CR0_WP), %eax
    mov %eax, %cr0

    lgdt gdtdesc

    mov $0x28, %ax
    ltr %ax
    mov $kernel_stack, %esp
    push $0x23
    push $user_stack
    push $0x1b
    push $user_task

    lret

user_task:
    nop
die:
    jmp die

.data

.align 4096
tss:
    .long 0
    .long kernel_stack
    .word 0x10, 0
    .long 0, 0, 0, 0
    .long pgdir
    .long 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    .long 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

gdt:    
    SEG_NULLASM
    SEG_ASM(STA_X|STA_R, 0x0, 0xffffffff)   # code seg
    SEG_ASM(STA_W, 0x0, 0xffffffff)         # data seg
    SEG_ASM_USER(STA_X|STA_R, 0x0, 0xffffffff)
    SEG_ASM_USER(STA_W, 0x0, 0xffffffff)

    .word 0, 0x1000
    .byte 0x10, 0x89, 0x80, 0x80

gdtdesc:
    .word (gdtdesc - gdt - 1)
    .long gdt

.align 4096
pgdir:  .long PTE_P|PTE_W|PTE_PS
    .fill 511, 4
    .long PTE_P|PTE_W|PTE_PS
    .fill 511, 4

    .fill 4096
kernel_stack:

    .fill 4096
user_stack:
```

Comment: Show us your code and the Global Descriptor Table dump. I don't know how to use/turn-on the feature in Qemu, but in [Bochs emulator](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/) the debugging interface has a **instruction tracing**  (http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook/user/internal-debugger.html)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I found where the problem lies. The access violation happens at paging.

Comment: Can you add some more details, how did you find the bug, anything that might be useful for future readers?

Comment: I reorganize my code and put it here. After I put the code, I suddenly came across that I enabled paging and didn't consider privilege problems in paging.